# should catkin_make_isolated generate some initial setup.* files without packages in src?

Tags: ros, catkin, catkin-make-isolated

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to write an automated script to setup a catkin isolated workspace chained with a rosbuild workspace (to be used by freshmen students here). Since there are no packages to begin with, no setup files are generated by catkin_make_isolated.

Any thoughts on how this can be achieved?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62901/should-catkin_make_isolated-generate-some-initial-setup.*-files-without-packages-in-src?/) by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2871 on 2013-05-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently `catkin_make_isolated` is not designed to do anything with an empty workspace. You can try to figure out some reasonable default behavior and open a pull request. We will be releasing `catkin` in a week or so, which would be a nice window for getting a change in.

The other thing you could do is to put `catkin` in the workspace, that way it isn't empty.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2013-05-21**:
patch submitted and accepted https://github.com/ros/catkin/commit/8c5ecb5cb83107756472f6c95b0313ad1a2f8195 This feature should be available in catkin > 0.5.65